# INotifyCollectionChanged: Added item does not appear at given index '0'

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a observable class. The Add methods works fine. But then I'm trying to call the Remove() method I get this error:

> "Added item does not appear at given index '0'"

but I'm setting the NotifyCollectionChangedAction enum to Remove as the code below.

```
    public class ObservableOrderResponseQueue : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<OrderResponse>
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    private List<OrderResponse> _list = new List<OrderResponse>();


    public void Add(OrderResponse orderResponse)
    {
        this._list.Add(orderResponse);
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, orderResponse, 0));
        }
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        OrderResponse order = this._list[index];
        this._list.RemoveAt(index);
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, order, index));
        }
    }

    public void Remove(OrderResponse orderResponse)
    {
        var item = _list.Where(o => o.OrderDetail.TrayCode == orderResponse.OrderDetail.TrayCode).FirstOrDefault();
        int index = _list.IndexOf(item);

        this._list.RemoveAt(index);
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, index));
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line raises the exception?

Comment: You should make a method to add or remove a set of objects all at once.

Comment: I was getting this error as well. Finally tracked it down to a bug in my override Equals and public static bool operator == on the object I was adding. Took hours to debug this so hopefully might save others some time.

Comment: If this collection is data-bound to a UI element, check whether the collection is being updated (in your case, when `Remove` was called) on a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure the error is with the `Remove` method? The error message and your source code indicate it is in the `Add` method. Try using the correct index `_list.Count - 1` in the constructor of `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`:

```
CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                                              NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, 
                                              orderResponse, _list.Count - 1)
                 );
```

Comment: Yes iam sure iam calling the Remove method. Thats why i dont get it. Why does this error appear.

Comment: @Tan: Did you change your `Add` method the way I asked you to do? If not, please do it, just to be sure!

Comment: Sorry! I thought i should change the Remove method. But it was the add method. Now everything works great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Now it works fine but i dont get it why do i have to use _list.Count - 1. why minus 1 in add function ?

Comment: Calling `List<T>.Add` adds the new element to the **end** of the list, i.e. the new element is the last one in the list, i.e. it has the index `list.Count - 1`. The constructor of `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` requires you to pass in the index of the newly added object, hence you pass `list.Count - 1`.

Comment: You can verify it by calling `_list.IndexOf(orderResponse)`. You will see, it will return `_list.Count - 1`.

Comment: I can confirm that this thoroughly confusing exception is raised on the `Remove` (!) callback, and is fixed by passing the correct index to the `Add` callback. Confusingly, not passing any index at all on `Add` (documented as a [valid thing to do!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653207.aspx)) also leads to this confusing exception message.

Comment: I faced this issue after implementing a "sorted" ObservableCollection class. When you add an element to the list, it will not necessarily be added to the end of the list. However, when raising the collection-change event for the "Add" action, WPF expects that the element is added to the end of the list. The way I managed to get around this was to first add the element to the end of the list and then move it to its correct index.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to guess, I'd say that this line...

```
var item = _list.Where(
    o => o.OrderDetail.TrayCode == orderResponse.OrderDetail.TrayCode)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

...because it calls `FirstOrDefault()`, may be returning `null`. Set a breakpoint and see what's actually going on.

To that end, why even do that query? Since you're passing in the object to be removed, why not simply do this:

```
int index = _list.IndexOf(item);
if (index >= 0)
    this._list.RemoveAt(index);
//then pass item to your eventargs since it was the object removed.
```

Even better, since `List<T>` has its own `Remove(T object)` method:

```
this._list.Remove(item);
//this may throw an exception or not if the item is not in that collection,
// which is behavior you should probably retain
```

---

#### Sidenotes

There is also a possible race condition in how you raise the `CollectionChanged` event. In between checking for `null` and raising it a subscriber could remove its delegate from the event. Here's an easy way to avoid that:

```
// initialize it with an empty lamda so it is never null
public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = (o,e) => {};
```

Now you can just raise it and never need to check if it is null:

```
public void Add(OrderResponse orderResponse)
{
    this._list.Add(orderResponse);
    CollectionChanged(this,
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
            orderResponse, this._list.Count - 1));
}
```

This doesn't make it completely thread-safe, but it's an easy way of making sure raising the event won't throw a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

I received this exception when I attempted to create a new `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` with the *Remove* parameter when passing an item that I used to look up in my internal list and not the actual item that was getting removed.

Once, I changed the item I passed into the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` to the actual item I was removing from my internal list the exception

> "Added item does not appear at given index.."

went away.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the issue with Reflector and figured out the cause of this exception might refer to `Equals` not returning true for actually equal objects in your list; or maybe `operator ==`.