# How to update ItemsSource automatically from own collection?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have created my own collection and implemented INotifyCollectionChanged.

```
public class ObservableSortedSet<T> : SortedSet<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public new bool Add(T item)
    {
        var result = base.Add(item);
        if (result)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(item,
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
        return result;
    }

    public new bool Remove(T item)
    {
        var result = base.Remove(item);
        if (result)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(item,
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
        return result;
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

However when I try to use this collection as ItemsSource in views, they do not update automatically when I e.g. remove an item. As I seen in other questions here, I should implement INotifyCollectionChanged. I did this and yet it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `remove` method does not work is that you have to add the index of the removed element.

I tried it this way and it does work:

View codebehind:

```
public ObservableSortedSet<String> Values { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Values = new ObservableSortedSet<string>();
        Values.Add("Test0");
        Values.Add("Test1");
        Values.Add("Test2");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Values.Add("Test" + Values.Count);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you try to remove an item?

Comment: yes and the remove works, when the index of the removed element is added.

Comment: I assume I should add this to invocation of CollectionChanged. How can I get an index of removed item, or can I use just 0?

Comment: Thats the problem :D

Comment: has you already read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883870/inotifycollectionchanged-help)

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with synchronization because i tried this code `public new bool Remove(T item)
        {
            bool result = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.ElementAt(i).Equals(item))
                {
                    result = base.Remove(item);
                    CollectionChanged?.Invoke(item,
                   new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, i));
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }`

Comment: Should the debugger indicate that I have some listener to my event?

Comment: Still not working, nevermind, I will refresh my ItemsSources manually. Thanks for help.