# NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs: Added item does not appear at given index (during removal)

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I implemented an ObservableStack, per this post: [Observable Stack and Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127136/observable-stack-and-queue/6245230#6245230). It's working 99% of the time, but in some cases - rarely & seemingly without reason - when I try to pop the stack, I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Added item does not appear at given index '1'.
   at MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   ...
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class ObservableStack<T> : Stack<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public new virtual void Push(T item)
    {
        base.Push(item);
        var e = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, base.Count-1);
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    public new virtual T Pop()
    {
        var item = base.Pop();
        var e = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, base.Count);
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
        return item;
    }

    //...
}
```

In the rare cases it happens, the exception is thrown on the call to CollectionChanged() in Pop().  This is similar to the question [INotifyCollectionChanged: Added item does not appear at given index '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883870/inotifycollectionchanged-added-item-does-not-appear-at-given-index-0) , but none of the answers seem applicable in this case.  Note that replacing base.count with -1 or 0 on the Remove line, where the exception is being thrown, causes it to *always* fail. Likewise if I just exclude the index from the event args, it always complains "Collection Remove event must specify item position."  I can technically make it work by changing the notification args to

```
var e = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
```

...But of course, that isn't actually correct, and I would like to get 'Remove' to report properly.  None of the items being inserted have an overridden Equals() or operator=.

A little more background: the stack is being used in an UndoHistory, where when values are changed, the previous values are pushed to the stack, & popped when I undo.  This works for the vast, vast majority of cases, which is why I'm having difficulty figuring out why the error is occurring in just a small number of cases.  And unfortunately, I've been thus far unsuccessful in whittling it down to a small self-contained example that always shows the issue.  For instance, in the real application, I might do an operation and undo it with no problem, but then do the same operation twice in a row, after which undoing will raise the exception.  In a smaller/simplified example, I can't get it to happen at all.  Note that the stack is also bound to an ItemsControl for displaying the undo history - though it's one-way only (i.e. the control isn't used for modifying the stack, only displaying its items).

Any ideas why it would throw such an exception in such seemingly random, rare cases would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is more than one thread involved? As a note, instead of checking CollectionChanged for null before invoking it, you could write a single statement: `CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);`

Comment: I don't believe so, but just to check, I added Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); - to both Push() & Pop(), & they both always report the same ID of 1.  So if that's a valid way to check, then no, just one thread involved.

Comment: There are, however, multiple instances of the stack. Shouldn't be on different threads tho.

Comment: You should provide the code line that throws the exception and a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Frankly, I am skeptical of your approach to implementing this anyway. It's unusual to have either a stack or queue be "observable", because those data structures are typically intended to be "observed" only one element at a time. To the extent that you might provide a collection-oriented view, the `ObservableCollection<T>` class itself provides that directly. I.e. rather than implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` yourself, your stack and queue classes should use `ObservableCollection<T>` as the backing data structure, and just delegate the event handling to that.

Comment: I.e. you can easily implement either stack or queue using `ObservableCollection<T>`. Just use methods like `Insert()`, `Add()`, and `RemoveAt()` to make appropriate modifications to the underlying collection in a stack- or queue-like way as appropriate.

Comment: @BionicCode: I did state: "the exception is thrown on the call to CollectionChanged() in Pop()." Regarding a minimal example, I'll work on seeing if I can pull one together - though unfortunately the exception doesn't seem to happen in very simple cases, which is part of the difficulty in debugging it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'd thought of doing that, but then every Insert(0, item) becomes O(n) - making every operation many times more expensive than it needs to be, no?

Answer (score 1):

This error isn't being thrown by your code but by another class that is subscribing to your events. Probably something in WPF. This class is verifying that a copy of your stack collection that it holds somewhere is still valid, and finding that it is not.

The 99% likely cause is that there are changes to your stack that are not generating `CollectionChanged` events.

The first problem is that when `Clear` is called you should issue a `Reset` event.

The second is that if someone casts your object to `Stack<T>` and calls `Push` or `Pull`, your code won't be hit. This happens because those methods aren't virtual, hence your need to declare your own versions with `new`. Declaring *your* methods as `virtual` does not change this.

You can't fix that. The solution is not to derive your class from `Stack` but to instead create a private `Stack` object inside it, and to then create your own methods that expose its functionality in a way that you are in complete control of.

Once you do this (and implement all events correctly!) the exceptions will go away.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your reply.  I edited my question to add a little deeper info on the exception (i.e. which WPF it was originating from).  Re: it's likely that there are changes not generating CollectionChanged events, how could that happen per the code above? Or is that exactly the scenario you were referring to where someone casts it to Stack<T>?

Comment: In any case, I went ahead & changed it to composition: don't inherit Stack, but instead wrap a private instance of a Stack object (& I just exposed the stuff I'm currently using). Unfortunately, the exceptions remain the same :/

Answer (score -2):

Both your posted `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` are created with wrong args.
A `Stack` is like a reversed collection: the last item added is the first to be removed and has always the index `0`. So in a `Stack` the change always takes place at index `0`.
Currently you are always reporting the last index, which is count - 1, which is the last item to pop, which is the first item pushed, which only points to the item that is currently popped when count == 1.

`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` with fixed change index:

```
public new virtual void Push(T item)
{
    base.Push(item);
    var e = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, 0);
    if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
        this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
}

public new virtual T Pop()
{
    var item = base.Pop();
    var e = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, 0);
    if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
        this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
    return item;
}
```

### Remarks

The point is, that when a collection is used with an `ItemsControl`, the control will only operate on the `ICollectionView` of the source collection. This `CollectionView` internally subscribes to the underlying collection's `CollectionChanged` event to track the changes. It does this because the collection view maintains a pointer, which includes `CurrentItem` and `CurrentPosition`.
In this context `CollectionView` validates the changed item and its index by tracking those info from add to remove. When adding an item, you currently report the last index e.g. `1`, but when removing this item, the true index is `0`. That's why the internal validation fails and the exception *"Added item does not appear at given index '1'."* is thrown.

Note that a data structure like a stack (or like a queue), is not considered index based. But the collection change notifications are.

To get the expected behavior, you should extend an index based collection like `ObservableCollection`. Then use `Insert` at `0` and `RemoveAt(0)` to provide the LIFO behavior.

If you want O(1) for access operations, you would have to implement e.g., `ICollection<T>` + `INotifyCollectionChanged` and use an array as backing store.
Always append to the array and remember the last index. But take care that when implementing the indexer or `GetEnumerator`, that you always return the "reversed" array: first added item has the index `0`. This way the UI gets the properly ordered collection view and you have your O(1) for push and pop operations.
The trick is to find a good initial array size to avoid resizing.

A stack is a data structure that only cares to return the last added item. You cannot move items or access items randomly (by index). That's why a Stack or Queue is not suited for the UI scenario. `ItemsControl` (and `CollectionChanged`) always operates index based.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223232/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-notifycollectionchangedeventargs-added-item).