# InvalidOperationException while sorting an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting, observablecollection

In my program I have `TreeView` nodes that I need to be able to shift up and down, basically change the order. My `TreeView` is an `ObservableCollection` of a specific Data Model. Each node has a property called "Rank", this is the value that I would like to sort the collection by. With that being said I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945461/how-do-i-sort-an-observable-collection). From that question I discovered this [blog page](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-sort-obversablecollection.html). I am attempting the second method involving the `sort` function of a `List`.

This is the example that I am looking at:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>(people);
list.Sort();
```

Please note that the "Rank" value of each node is in working order and changing correctly. I just need to find a way to re-order the collection based off of that property and reflect it in the View.

**My Problem:** When trying to implement the above solution I get an `InvalidOperationException`. I feel like I do not understand how to tell the `List` to sort based off of rank.

What my code looks like:

```
List<TreeModel> sortedTree = new List<TreeModel>(TreeCollection);
sortedTree.Sort();
```

What am I missing here? How do I sort the collection based off of the rank property and reflect those changes in the view?

Thank you.

*I believe I may have posted about this before, so if for some reason this question is too similar my older one, I'll just delete the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws `InvalidOperationException` its component type does not have a default comparison:

> The default comparer Comparer.Default cannot find an implementation of the IComparable generic interface or the IComparable interface for type T.

You can however supply the comparison as the [first parameter to `Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
sortedTree.Sort((x, y) => x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank));
```

To pass the sorted items back to the original collection, you could either clear/repopulate `CurrentCollection`, or simply assign it a new instance (don't forget to `RaisePropertyChanged` if you do the latter):

```
CurrentCollection = new ObservableCollection<TreeModel>(sortedTree);
```

Comment: Okay, so this makes it so that the `List` will sort based off of the integer stored in Rank. After doing that won't I need to set the current `ObservableCollection` equal to the new sorted one?

Comment: @Ericafterdark yes exactly, you'd need to either create a new `ObservableCollection`, or clear/re-populate the existing one (the former is probably easier).

Comment: this is what I just did: `CurrentCollection = new ObservableCollection<TreeModel>(sortedTree);`. It doesn't seem to affect the view though. Maybe I am forgetting PropertyChanged?

Comment: @Ericafterdark right, if you replace the collection, you'd need to raise PropertyChanged ...

Comment: Worked like a charm! You might want to add the code that I used in that comment there to your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `property name` on which you want to sort your list like this -

```
sortedTree = sortedTree.OrderBy(m => m.Rank).ToList();
```