# C# - Sorting ObservableCollection "'utils' is inaccesible due to its protection level"

Tags: c#, sorting, observablecollection

I am trying to sort my observable collection by numbers. I found here on this forum this post: 
[How do I sort an observable collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945461/how-do-i-sort-an-observable-collection/16344936#16344936)

Everything is working fine till the line:

```
return Utils.LogicalStringCompare(a.Penize, b.Penize);
```

Where i get this error: 
"'Utils' is inaccesible due to its protection level."

My code:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable
    {
        List<T> sorted = collection.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
            collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sorted[i]), i);
    }
}
public class Uzivatel : IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(object o)
    {
        Uzivatel a = this;
        Uzivatel b = (Uzivatel)o;
        return Utils.LogicalStringCompare(a.Penize, b.Penize);
    }
    public int Penize{get;set;}
}
```

Can somebody help me with this please ? 
(Problem is still there even when i set that Extensions class to public.)

I dont want to use this insted, because its badly sorting numbers (1005 < 15 -_-):

```
return string.Compare(a.Penize.ToString(), b.Penize.ToString());
```

I will be happy for any help you will give me.

Comment: `Utils` is not marked `public`, just like your `Extensions` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your class Utils is accessible in Uzivatel  class. Use public access modifier for making it accessible. like:

```
public class Utils 
{
 //Your properties and methods
}
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot, that i had private class :D