# How to cope with an Observable collection of classes

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, observablecollection

I have following TracefieldPartProgramClass

```
public class TracefieldPartProgramClass
{
    public TracefieldPartProgramClass() { }
    public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>> obcTraceFieldPartProgram = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>>();
}
```

I use it to make the following collection:

```
ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass>();
```

now after having filled it I want to be able to sort as I want (say on the Tracefield[0]).
So I implemented this:

```
private ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass> SortOnTracefield(ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass> obcToSort)
{
var obcSorted = new ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass>();
obcSorted = obcToSort.OrderBy(w => w.obcTraceFieldPartProgram[0].Item3.ToString());<--- this is where I get the error
return obcSorted;
```

}

but when I do it, I get this error:

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you are trying to assign an `IOrderedEnumerable` to a variable of type `ObservableCollection`, which is not possible.

But luckily, `ObservableCollection` has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable` and prefills it with the items of that `IEnumerable`.

So, in order to make that error disappear, use that:

```
var sortedEnumerable = obcToSort.OrderBy(w => w.obcTraceFieldPartProgram[0].Item3.ToString());
obcSorted = new ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass>(sortedEnumerable );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
private ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass> SortOnTracefield(ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass> obcToSort)
{
    var sorted = obcToSort.OrderBy(w => w.obcTraceFieldPartProgram[0].Item3.ToString();
    return new ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass>(sorted);
}
```

You can pass an IEnumerable to the observable collection's constructor.

---

However, that returns a new instance of the collection. So, if the unsorted instance was bound to the GUI, that may not update your GUI. Another approch to support sorting is to use the [ICollectionView](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/).

---

The SO question [how-do-i-sort-an-observable-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945461/how-do-i-sort-an-observable-collection) may be intersting for you too. The following extension method can be used for sorting `ObservableCollection`s without recreation:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable
    {
        List<T> sorted = collection.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
            collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sorted[i]), i);
    }
}
```

However, your `TracefieldPartProgramClass` class needs to implement `IComparable` or you'll need to implement a custom `IComparer<TracefieldPartProgramClass>` and pass it the Sort method.

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.OrderBy` doesn't return an `ObservableCollection` but an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can create a new with the [`List<T>` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var obcSortedList = obcToSort
    .OrderBy(w => w.obcTraceFieldPartProgram[0].Item3.ToString())
    .ToList();  
var obcSorted = new ObservableCollection<EasyRunBinSerializableData.TracefieldPartProgramClass>(obcSortedList);
```

Comment: Why do you use the IList constructor instead of the IEnumerable one? Does that have any performance benefits?

Comment: @Domysee: the [`List<T>` constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,f89eec626d3cfff1) is a no-op, the `IEnumerable<T>` constructor will create a list anyway by enumerating all elements. So you can use both.

Comment: However the `List<T>` constructor also creates a copy of the passed list ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,f63ea2601f5edbbb)), so `IEnumerable<T>` constructor looks more appropriate to me.

Comment: @IvanStoev: haven't seen the comment about the VSWhidbey bug 562681, so you're right. Then i'd also prefer the `IEnumerable<T>` constructor if i don't have a list already.